# Contents of twitter bootstrap tab are mixing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm still new in creating websites using twitter bootstrap. I was planning to have a tab that contains the assessment of a student but the contents of my tabs are mixing even though the id's are correct. For example, the contents of the payment history are seen in the other tabs although I am not missing any opening and closing tags. The values there are still dummy data. Here is the code:

```
<section id="main-content" " ng-controller="studCtrl">
        <section class="wrapper">
            <div class="content-panel"> 
                <div class="row mt">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h2>Student's Assessment</h2>
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#distribution" data-toggle="tab">Distribution</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="#misc-fees" data-toggle="tab">Miscellaneous Fees</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="#other-fees" data-toggle="tab">Other Fees</a></li>
                            <!--<li class=""><a href="#iMent" data-toggle="tab">Installment Fees</a></li-->
                            <li class=""><a href="#payment-hist" data-toggle="tab">Payment History</a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="distribution">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                                                <thead>
                                                    ...
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    ...
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div><!--table-responsive-->
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="misc-fees">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            ...
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            ...
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div><!--table-responsive--> 
                            </div>

                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="other-fees">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            ...
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            ...
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="payment-hist">
                                payment history
                            </div><!--payment history-->

                        </div><!-- end of tab content-->

                    </div><!--col-lg-12-->
                </div> <!--row mt-->
             </div><!--content-panel-->
        </section><!--/wrapper -->
    </section> <!--main-content-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<section id="main-content" " ng-controller="studCtrl">
```

The code here has one more double quote sign. At first, you should remove the sign.

But in case still not works properly after removing the sign, than I suggest you may check DOM structure using dev tools in browser(chrome/firefox/...).